# How does casting this pointer to an unrelated class work?

Tags: c++, class, casting, reinterpret-cast

This confuses me because if "this" points to its own object, how would casting it (**without inheritance**) allow me to access other class members? I think I'm just overall confused on what exactly casting "this" is doing for the compiler, considering its address doesn't change.

```
template<class T>
class A 
{
public:
    void call_fn()
    {
        reinterpret_cast<T*>(this)->fn();
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    void fn()
    {
        std::cout << "B function called" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<B> obj;
    obj.call_fn(); //prints out "B function called"
}
```

Comment: In this case, the cast says "pretend that `this` is actually a pointer to `T`". The compiler obliges you. But pretending doesn't make it true. Whatever happens is purely accident. Formally, the behavior of this program is undefined; the C++ standard doesn't tell you what the program does. If `B` is more complex, e.g., has data members that `fn` uses, the problem will become clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-static method call is just like a plain function call but with a hidden `this` parameter pointing at the object. The code shown is *roughly* equivalent to the following:

```cpp
class A {};
class B {};

void B_fn(B* this);

void A_call_fn(A* this) {
    B_fn(reinterpret_cast<B*>(this));
}; 

void B_fn(B* this) {
    std::cout << "B function called" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    A obj;
    A_call_fn(&obj);
}
```

`A::call_fn()` is type-casting its `A* this` parameter to `B*`, and then calling `B::fn()` with that casted pointer as its `B* this` parameter value. A [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) is effectively a brute-force cast, it really goes out of its way to try to oblige your request. So you are telling the compiler that you know what you are doing and just accept it. So it does.  But you are invoking *undefined behavior*, because like you said, `A` and `B` are unrelated types.

The code *happens* to work, but only because `B::fn()` makes no use of its `B* this` parameter, so it doesn't matter whether `this` is actually pointing at a valid `B` object or not. The code is ultimately no different than if you had done this instead:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::cout << "B function called" << std::endl;
}
```

But, if you were to change `B` to hold a non-static data member that `B::fn()` actually uses, then the code will fail more noticeably.